# Trouble Installing Gevent In Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, gevent, python-3.5

I'm trying to install Gevent in Python 3.5 in PyCharm.  I've had no problems installing it in 2.7.  But it will not work in 3.4 or 3.5.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

I've tried installing directly using pip & easy install.  Here's the error I get:

```
localhost:~ user$ Python3.5 easy_install gevent
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

localhost:~ user$ Python3.5 pip install gevent
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've tried moving from 2.7 to 3.5 using the steps outlined here:

https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Still no luck getting it to work on 3.5.

I've tried downloading gevent & running the setup.py in Python Launcher 3.5.  Here's the error that gives:

```
cd '/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/setup.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
localhost:~ user$ cd '/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/setup.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Running 'make ' in /Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python util/cythonpp.py -o gevent.corecext.c gevent/core.ppyx
Running cython -o gevent.corecext.c gevent/core.pyx  # !EV_USE_SIGNALFD && !defined(LIBEV_EMBED) && !defined(_WIN32)
sh: cython: command not found
Path: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
Bin: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS files: Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 789, in <module>
    process_filename(filename, options.output_file)
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 98, in process_filename
    output = run_cython(pyx_filename, sourcehash, output_filename, banner, comment)
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 546, in run_cython
    system(command, comment)
  File "util/cythonpp.py", line 562, in system
    raise AssertionError('%r failed with code %s' % (command, result))
AssertionError: 'cython -o gevent.corecext.c gevent/core.pyx' failed with code 32512
make: *** [gevent/gevent.corecext.c] Error 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/setup.py", line 426, in <module>
    run_setup(ext_modules, run_make=run_make)
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/setup.py", line 378, in run_setup
    make()
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/setup.py", line 232, in make
    system('make ' + targets)
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/setup.py", line 142, in system
    if _system(cmd):
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/gevent-master/setup.py", line 138, in _system
    return check_call(cmd, shell=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'make ' returned non-zero exit status 2
localhost:gevent-master user$
```

Here's the full error when trying to install gevent in PyCharm:

```
DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
Downloading/unpacking gevent
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py) egg_info for package gevent

Downloading/unpacking greenlet>=0.4.7 (from gevent)
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/greenlet/setup.py) egg_info for package greenlet

Installing collected packages: gevent, greenlet
  Running setup.py install for gevent
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    Running '/bin/sh /private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/libev/configure > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/libev
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 317, in <module>
        run_setup(ext_modules)
      File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 312, in run_setup
        "Development Status :: 4 - Beta"])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.1-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 554, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 348, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 457, in build_extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 234, in build_extension
        self.gevent_prepare(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 231, in gevent_prepare
        configure(self, ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 139, in configure_libev
        make_universal_header('config.h', 'SIZEOF_LONG', 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T', 'SIZEOF_TIME_T')
      File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 111, in make_universal_header
        print >>f, line
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pip-tc4dbvhv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/_ssl2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/_sslgte279.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/_threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/baseserver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/coros.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/event.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/fileobject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/hub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/local.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/os.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/pywsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/resolver_ares.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/resolver_thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/select.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/socket.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/subprocess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/threading.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/threadpool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

copying gevent/wsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent

warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.



running build_ext

Running '/bin/sh /private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/libev/configure > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/libev

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 317, in <module>

    run_setup(ext_modules)

  File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 312, in run_setup

    "Development Status :: 4 - Beta"])

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.4.1-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 554, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 348, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 457, in build_extensions

    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 234, in build_extension

    self.gevent_prepare(ext)

  File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 231, in gevent_prepare

    configure(self, ext)

  File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 139, in configure_libev

    make_universal_header('config.h', 'SIZEOF_LONG', 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T', 'SIZEOF_TIME_T')

  File "/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py", line 111, in make_universal_header

    print >>f, line

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pip-tc4dbvhv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/t4/xp7tp60132xfvpcsglylyyjr0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/gevent
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: I tried that.  But it's installing to 2.7:  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet-0.4.9-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg (from gevent)

Comment: *alpha release for testing Python 3 and PyPy support* https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent/1.1a1 ,*There is no released version of gevent that supports Python 3. The development version features partial support, but it is not yet ready for release (e.g., there are known problems with sockets).* https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/566

Comment: Try the development version but bear in mind  *Python 3.5 has preliminary support*,  `Python3.5 pip install 'cython>=0.23.4' git+git://github.com/gevent/gevent.git#egg=gevent`

Comment: Thanks you.  Installing https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent/1.1a1 version worked.

Comment: No worries, you may find the development version better in regards to python3.5, 1.1a1 was released in june

Comment: Please don't answer your question **in** the question, instead, post an answer containing the solution